# Joining Two query

Tags: sql

```
select a.Enquiry_Id,a.Ckeck_In,a.check_Out,a.Hotel_Name,a.Meal_Plan,a.Room_Type,a.Occupancy_Type,a.Room_QT,a.Adults from Accomodation a 
where a.Enquiry_Id = 74

select q.Enquiry_Id,q.Start,q1.Stay_At from Quick_Plan q,Quick_Plan q1 where q.Enquiry_Id = 74 and q1.Enquiry_Id = 74 and q.Stay_At = q1.Start
```

result of 1st query is

```
74  2013-08-03  2013-08-04  ADS CP          deluxe  Double  1   2
```

and the result of 2nd query is

```
74  Ahmedabad   Agra
```

nw i want to combine these two query so that i get the result like

```
74  2013-08-03  2013-08-04  ADS CP          deluxe  Double  1   2 Ahmedabad Agra
```

Comment: I might be tired; what is the difference between the desired result and and the first select result?

Comment: @u07ch the two extra fields returned by the second select result.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the easiest way would be to use CTEs as they won't need much modification.

```
;WITH FirstCTE AS
(
    SELECT    a.Enquiry_Id, 
              a.Ckeck_In,
              a.check_Out,  
              a.Hotel_Name, 
              a.Meal_Plan,
              a.Room_Type,
              a.Occupancy_Type,
              a.Room_QT,
              a.Adults 
    FROM      Accomodation a 
    WHERE     a.Enquiry_Id = 74
),
SecondCTE AS
(
    SELECT    q.Enquiry_Id,
              q.Start,
              q1.Stay_At 
    FROM      Quick_Plan q,
              Quick_Plan q1 
    WHERE     q.Enquiry_Id = 74 
              and q1.Enquiry_Id = 74 
              and q.Stay_At = q1.Start
)

SELECT * 
FROM   FirstCTE F
       JOIN SecondCTE S
       ON F.Enquiry_Id = S.Enquiry_Id
```

I think that the proper way would be:

```
SELECT    a.Enquiry_Id, 
          a.Ckeck_In,
          a.check_Out,  
          a.Hotel_Name, 
          a.Meal_Plan,
          a.Room_Type,
          a.Occupancy_Type,
          a.Room_QT,
          a.Adults ,
          q.Start,
          q1.Stay_At 
FROM      Accomodation a 
          JOIN Quick_Plan q
              ON a.Enquiry_Id = q.Enquiry_Id
          JOIN Quick_Plan q1 
              ON q.Enquiry_Id = q1.Enquiry_Id 
              and q.Stay_At = q1.Start
WHERE     a.Enquiry_Id = 74
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a.Enquiry_Id and q.Enquiry_Id are the keys you use to join,

```
 SELECT a.Enquiry_Id, a.Ckeck_In, a.check_Out, a.Hotel_Name, a.Meal_Plan,  a.Room_Type, a.Occupancy_Type, a.Room_QT, a.Adults,q.Start, q1.Stay_At 
 FROM Accomodation a 
 INNER JOIN Quick_Plan q ON a.Enquiry_Id = q.Enquiry_Id
 INNER JOIN Quick_Plan q1 ON q1.Enquiry_Id = q.Enquiry_Id
 WHERE a.Enquiry_Id = 74 AND
    q.Stay_At = q1.Start
```

Comment: not getting the right result from either of three answers plz suggest some other query. al these querys are working like cross join for my data.

Comment: The problem is, I don't really understand your second query. At first I thought it was some sort of self-JOIN on your Quick_Plan table, but then I noticed that you use Enquiry_Id (which I assumed to be your primary key), which makes a non-sense to me.

So could you please provide some more info about your db data? 
Providing data from Enquiry_Id #74 of both tables would be great...

Comment: i have two tables first is quickplan and another is accomodation the quickplan table contain the info about tour like checkindate checkout day tour strat from tour ends at stayat places and accomodation contain the information about hotels where the person is styaing i have to create a voucher where i need the some information from accomodation table and some from quickplan the info from quickplan is retrived by applying selfjoin in quickplan table now what i want to join these two queries. if still dere is some prblm in understanding the prblm i cn give u the struture n data of both tables

Comment: RH - 02/09/2013 - 4 2013-09-10 2013-09-11 Abad Airport Hotel MAP        Please Select Please Select 1 2
RH - 02/09/2013 - 4 2013-09-11 2013-09-12 Devinshare CP         DELUX Single 1 2

Comment: I guess the two rows are from Accomodation table, is this true? First of all, I'd suggest you not to save "Please select" as a value when your value is undefined. Something like NULL, '', or even 0 would be better. Secondly, it's not performing to save ENUM types such you RoomType as Strings. You'd better save them as integer and then convert them with a mapping table. For example 0=SINGLE, 1=DOUBLE, 3=DELUXE, etc.

Comment: Yes please post your tables structure (both of them) and some rows data, cause I'm afraid your problem could be related to them.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
a.Enquiry_Id,
a.Ckeck_In,
a.check_Out,
a.Hotel_Name,
a.Meal_Plan,
a.Room_Type,
a.Occupancy_Type,
a.Room_QT,
a.Adults,
q.Enquiry_Id,
q.Start,
q1.Stay_At 
from 
Accomodation a, 
Quick_Plan q, 
Quick_Plan q1 
where 

q.Enquiry_Id = 74 
and q1.Enquiry_Id = 74 
and q.Stay_At = q1.Start 
and a.Enquiry_Id = 74
```

try this